# Can't update using system updater, 404 Not Found error for sevenmachines PPA

Tags: package-management, update-manager

This is the message it gives me:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sevenmachines/flash/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sevenmachines/flash/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those PPAs are outdated or not properly set up. For the time being uncheck (do not remove completely) those PPAs, save and then in terminal do `sudo apt-get update`